# Is it possible to get good hallucination while suffering from schizophrenia?

Tags: neuroscience, schizophrenia, hallucinations

> Schizophrenia : A disorder that affects a person's ability to think, feel and behave clearly.
> The exact cause of schizophrenia isn't known, but a combination of genetics, environment and altered brain chemistry and structure may play a role.

So basically you get hallucination in Schizophrenia. I watched a [**Video**](https://youtu.be/EvN7R1oRuOI) about Schizophrenia and it say something like this .

*People who suffer from Schizophrenia have hallucination like* :

- Fishes are swimming all around them.
- Books are melting.
- Strange voices are ordering them to to something.

*But can anyone have hallucination like* :

- a woman is loving them(sexually and romantically) .
- They have many good friends
- The voice in the head are telling them answers in an exam.

**So basically can anyone get hallucination that they will enjoy**.

Comment: Can you please provide some background information on what you have read regarding the subject. That way an answerer can help you more effectively without repeating knowns. *"Strange voices are ordering them to to something"* can also not be "ordering them to do something" but could be threatening to the sufferer.  What have you read about the different types of hallucinations sufferers can experience?  Have you read that they are only auditory and/or visual, or have you read than they can be olfactory too?  Are tactile hallucinations possible from what you read?

Comment: @ChrisRogers I watched a video on YouTube. You can see it. It's in the question

Comment: well there's not enough data to prove this, but this definitely is true in films like Joker and Bollywood movies like Lage Raho Munna Bhai tho this would probably not be identified as schizophrenia

Comment: @RaghavendraSingh movies should not be taken as a reliable source of information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer appears to be yes, to a certain degree, though there seems to be a need for more research in this area of viewing hallucinations as a boon, rather than a curse.

The positive symptoms of schizophrenia, in this case, hallucinations, often vary in how they appear to the subject. Some argue that one of the keys to how one might react to the manifestation of hallucinations has to do with their culture.

[Larøi et al (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1093/schbul/sbu012), shows that changing perspective on the hallucinations in a more positive direction might help cope or manage the symptoms, they emphasize that cultural background needs to be considered, as there may not be a need for an intervention or help if the individual's culture does not view the hallucinations as bizarre or abnormal.

A great example would be the way people claim to be able to see or talk with a deity that has proliferated throughout the culture they inhabit. It becomes something that might be giving them those answers to an exam or that the hallucination is in love with them.
It should also be noted that not everybody who has hallucinations is going to show up in a clinical setting, so we still have do not have much data on how these symptoms manifest in different cultures. Something which Larøi et al mention in their article.

Reference:

Larøi, F., Luhrmann, T. M., Bell, V., Christian Jr, W. A., Deshpande, S., Fernyhough, C., ... & Woods, A. (2014). Culture and hallucinations: overview and future directions. *Schizophrenia bulletin, 40*(Suppl_4), S213-S220. https://doi.org/10.1093/schbul/sbu012